# EclipseFP on Indigo, issues with Maven?

Tags: eclipse, haskell, maven, eclipse-fp

I'm trying to install EclipseFP, using the usual Eclipse "Install new software" approach. However, at the "Installation Details" window, it says "This operation cannot be completed", giving me the following details:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364
      (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364)
  Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138547364
      (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138547364)
    requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]'
    but it could not be found
```

I just barely downloaded a fresh Eclipse:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers    
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
```

Does EclipseFP actually work on Indigo? Do I need to download an older Eclipse? Or perhaps there are additional steps I need to take to install Maven? (I don't want to download/install Maven if I don't have to.)

Comment: There are a lot of known issues of sharing an eclipse instance(the eclipse is read-only for running user, such as put eclipse folder under "Program files" with UAC enable on Windows 7). Pls try move eclipse to a folder your user has write permission.

Comment: @Kane that should be an answer; that fixed the problem.

Comment: You can watch [bug 339659](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339659) that reported the similar issue with your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Kane neglected to turn his comment into an answer, I may as well state it plainly here:

This issue arises when you put the Eclipse folder in a location where Windows will have issues with access control (e.g. the Program Files folder). By moving the folder to my personal user's folder, I was able to use Eclipse normally without this issue.